# Multi-threading. If I use semaphore can I create a lot of threads at start or should I have only few?

Tags: c++, multithreading, parallel-processing

Multi-threading. If I use semaphore can I create a lot of threads at start or should I have only few?

I have a vector of points. The length of vector is K. K = 100. But maybe this value will increase. 
Each point is n-dimentional vector.
I have an array of pointers to a functions. The size is 10. And I have to compute each function for every point.
And store it in txt file
And I need to use multi-threading for this.

I'm new to parallelization.

I have 4 cores. So I want to run 4 threads at the same time.
I know there is semaphore with counter = 4.
All functions do not share variables.
I think they share only txt file.

Is it a bad practice to create at first 100 threads?
And after that to use semaphore with counter = 4

4 threads run simultaneously, 96 waiting.
After one of them done all things, there will be again
4 threads, but 95 waiting.
Do waiting threads take up memory or some other resources?

Or I should create new thread only when one of 4 running threads will be finished?

Answer (score 0):

Waiting threads take up memory, and switching between threads takes up clock cycles. This involves a call to the kernel, and a context switch ain't cheap. When you're trying to parallelize a process that's easy to divy up into small chunks, it's usually more efficient to have the same number of threads as you have cores.